# Charge of a circuit, 2nd order ODE with initial conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, initial-value-problems

I'm currently going over some ODEs, some help would be appreciated, a past exam says the following:

An electrical circuit consists of a capacitor, $C$, an inductance, $L$, an ammeter with resistance $R$, and an open switch, all connected in series.The capacitor initially carries a charge $Q_0$. At time $t = 0$
, the switch is closed and it is observed that current starts to flow and that, initially, the current is given by $I_0 = -\frac{5R}{L} $. The charge carried by the capacitor is described by the differential equation
$$L\frac{dI}{dt} + RI + \frac{Q}{C} = 0$$
As $I = \frac{dQ}{dt}$, we can write the above equation as $$L \frac{d^2 Q}{dt^2} + R\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C} = 0$$
We are asked to prove that $Q(t) = Q_0e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ is a solution, which I did.
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{1}{C} - \frac{R^2}{4L^2}}$$

My question is: How do you solve for $Q_0$ and $\phi$?

EDIT: The question says to find the above values, surely that would mean values of R, L and C are needed? So would it just mean find the functions?

EDIT 2: [Here's](http://prntscr.com/irube5) the question in its entirety.

Comment: $Q_{0}$ is constant initial charge of capacitor you needn't solve for it

Comment: @veereshpandey the paper asks you to calculate the values of $Q_0$ and $\phi$ , I understood what $Q_0$ is, just not how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating the general solution

\begin{align}
  Q(t) &= e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}(A\cos \omega t+B\sin \omega t) \\
  Q'(t) &= e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}
  \left[
    \left( \omega B-\frac{AR}{2L} \right) \cos \omega t-
    \left( \omega A+\frac{BR}{2L} \right) \sin \omega t
  \right]
\end{align}

Equating the boundary conditions
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    Q(0) &= Q_0 \\
    Q'(0) &= I_0
  \end{align}
\right.$$

Put $t=0$,

$$\left \{
\begin{align}
  Q_0 &= A \\
  I_0 &= \omega B-\frac{AR}{2L}
\end{align}
\right.$$

On solving,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    A &= Q_0 \\
    B &= \frac{I_0}{\omega}+\frac{Q_0 R}{2L\omega}
  \end{align}
\right.$$

Therefore,

> \begin{align}
>   Q(t) &= e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}
>   \left[
>     Q_0 \cos \omega t+
>     \left( \frac{I_0}{\omega}+\frac{Q_0 R}{2L\omega} \right) \sin \omega t
>   \right] \\
>   Q_{\text{envelope}} &= e^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}}
>   \sqrt{Q_0^2+
>   \left( \frac{I_0}{\omega}+\frac{Q_0 R}{2L\omega} \right)^2} \\
>   \tan \phi &= -\frac{1}{\omega}
>   \left( \frac{I_0}{Q_0}+\frac{R}{2L} \right)
> \end{align}

Comment: Can you walk me through the steps of what you did? I assume you've done the complementary equation to get the first line, then differentiated and substituted to get the next few. There I get lost.

Comment: The first line is the general solution for $Q(t)$, differentiating gives the current $Q'(t)$, put $t=0$ to equate initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

there is something wrong in the question

$I_{0}\neq-5\dfrac{R}{L}$

because LHS has S.I. unit in $Amperes$. whereas R.H.S has S.I. unit in $(seconds)^-1$

so, this information is dimensionally  incorrect .they can never be equal

Comment: Are you sure? R would be in $\Omega$ and L in $H$ I believe. What they are in Base SI should be equal to $I$. Surely a university wouldn't have such an error in the question.

Comment: @Callum: S.I. unit of $\dfrac{L}{R}$ i.e,time constant of LR circuit, is $seconds$ so it's reciprocal $\dfrac{R}{L}$ must have S.I . unit as $ seconds^{-1} $

Answer (score 0):

a) there is a typo in your expression for $\omega$: it shall be
$$
\omega  = \sqrt {{1 \over {LC}} - {{R^{\,2} } \over {4L^{\,2} }}}  = \sqrt {{1 \over {LC}}} \;\,\sqrt {1 - {{\left( {R/\left( {2L} \right)} \right)^{\,2} } \over {LC}}} 
$$

b) you shall write the general solution as
$$
Q(t) = Ae^{\, - \,{R \over {2L}}\,t} \cos \left( {\omega t + \varphi } \right)
$$
which then gives
$$
I(t) =  - \,{R \over {2L}}Ae^{\, - \,{R \over {2L}}\,t} \cos \left( {\omega t + \varphi } \right) - \omega Ae^{\, - \,{R \over {2L}}\,t} \sin \left( {\omega t + \varphi } \right)
$$

c) you shall then impose the initial conditions
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  Q(0) = Q_{\,0}  = A\cos \varphi  \hfill \cr 
  I(0) = I_{\,0}  =  - \,{R \over {2L}}A\cos \varphi  - \omega A\sin \varphi  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
to get
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \tan \varphi  =  - {1 \over \omega }\left( {I_{\,0} /Q_{\,0}  + {R \over {2L}}} \right) \hfill \cr 
  A = Q_{\,0} /\cos \varphi  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

d) dimensionally wise $I_0$ cannot be $-5R/L$ (which has the dimension of 1/time), as already rightly pointed out by *v. pandey*,
it might be probably $I_0/Q_0=-5R/L$.

e) also, it is physically impossible, in a series RLC circuit, that immediately upon closing the switch you
can have a non-null current: the L will impede that to occur; you will have instead a current that starts from zero with a derivative $V_0/L=Q_0/(LC)$ (apart the sign).

Comment: How does $Q(0) = Q_0$ imply $\phi = 0$?

Comment: @callum: you are right: there was some confusion around, I recasted my answer to try and put the picture in focus